# Blocked list in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to generate a list of my blocked contacts in Gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be possible in earlier versions of Gmail, but not anymore. A possible workaround is, if you download and run the Google Talk client, and go to `Settings > Blocked`, there is a list of people you have blocked.